# How can I add a performance counter to a category i have already created

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

I have created a PerformanceCounterCategory like below

```
var category = PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("MyCat", "Cat Help",
    PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, "MyCounter", "Counter Help);
```

How can I add a new counter to the category to monitor another item?
I cannot find the api for it.

Comment: Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4742793/52277  describes how to preserve counters before deleting and re-creating category

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I did a research on this a while back and it doesn't seem to be possible to add counters to an existing category, what you would have to do it to recreate the same category with addition of the new counter.

Comment: +1 Use `PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete` followed by `PerformanceCounterCategory.Create`.

Answer (score -4):

```
PerformanceCounter lCounter = new PerformanceCounter(Category, CounterName, 
                                                     false);
lCounter.MachineName = ".";
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that when i fire my work laptop up in the morning

Comment: First setup your CounterCategory with all the counters and their type as below

var lCounters = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
lCounters.Add(new CounterCreationData(lCounterName, lounterHelp, lCounterType));
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(pCategory, lCategoryHelp, PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, lCounters);

Then when you want an instance of the counter, check if the category / counter exists and then do the following....

var lCounter = new PerformanceCounter(pCategory, pCounterName, false);
lCounter.MachineName = ".";

Hope this helps.