# Powershell - new performance counter is not being created

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am struggeling with the problem in subject.

I have this code:

```
   $category_name = "JCM"
   $counter_name = "counter5"

   $categoryExists =    [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Exists($category_name)

   # If category does not exist yet:
   If (-Not $categoryExists)
   {
       [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Create($category_name,    "", [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategoryType]::SingleInstance,    $counter_name, "") | Out-Null
   }

   # create counter:
   $perfmonCounter = New-Object    System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter($category_name, $counter_name, "", $false)
   Write-Host ($perfmonCounter | Format-List | Out-String)
   $perfmonCounter.RawValue = 0
```

The first time I run it - it creats the category and the counter in it.
But when I change the counter name to counter 6, it doesn't add it to the category!
And this is althogh write-host shows me this:

> CategoryName     : JCM CounterHelp      :  CounterName      : counter6
>   CounterType      :  InstanceLifetime : Global InstanceName     : 
>   ReadOnly         : False MachineName      : . RawValue         : 0
>   Site             :  Container        :

What is wrong here?

I run on Window 7 64 bit, powershell 4.0, .Net 4.5

Thank you.

Comment: ["... it doesn't seem to be possible to add counters to an existing category, what you would have to do it to recreate the same category with addition of the new counter"]


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958164/how-can-i-add-a-performance-counter-to-a-category-i-have-already-created

Comment: Hi Anton. Yes I saw this post. But isn't it ridicules that it is not possible? What could be the reason ? Anyway, I have added all my counters all together because of lack of choice...